# Why does pip installs a package outside my virtual environment?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

After doing a source of the virtual environment I try

```
pip install -U --no-deps django-social-auth
```

and it returns:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_social_auth-0.6.9-py2.6.egg-info/dependency_links.txt'
```

Why is it trying to write outside the virtualenv?

Comment: can you make sure the python you are invoking is actually the one from the virtual env ?

Comment: Indeed it is the one installed in the system and not the one in the virtual env

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran into this problem when I renamed the directory containing my virtual environment. The hard path pip was using was no longer correct.

Update the shebang in the pip script to point to your virtual environment's python executable.

Comment: great! I opened the virtual env /bin/pip to realize the shebang was not pointing to the virtual env's python executable. I have updated it but when I activate this virtual env and do 'which python' I still get the system's python and not the virtual env's. Yet it is a very good answer so far. Marking it as accepted.

Comment: Yes, I think you need to run /path/to/virtualenv/bin/python

Comment: This shouldn't be upvoted, just build a new virtualenv if you changed the path, don't muck around with editing shebangs.  First, you're very likely to have many, many such hardcoded paths not only in the bin directory, but also site-packages, second they're meant to be disposable & rebuildable. @Bastian, to make sure your `source` command was successful, try `echo $VIRTUAL_ENV`

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, either you are executing a pip that is not part of the virtualenv, or you are, but the python interpreter that gets executed is not part of the virtualenv. Check if the pip you are executing is the right one with `which pip`, and force the python from the virtualenv by using `your_envdir/bin/python pip <arguments>`, instead of just invoking plain pip.

This is strange, because if you correctly activated the environment with bin/activate, you should get the correct pip. Are you sure you activated with `. bin/activate`, and not `sh bin/activate` ? They are two different things. Did the prompt change ?

Comment: You are right, which pip returns /usr/bin/pip. I used 'source apps/virtual_environments/my_project/bin/activate' and the prompt changed to '(my_project)user@host:~$'. And when I try to use the pip that is in the virtual env I get: 'python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory'.

Comment: Any idea about what could cause this?

Comment: @Bastian: you have no python in the virtual env ?

Comment: Yes, I can see there is a Python in there.

Comment: @Bastian: ok so there are three possibilities: 1) the python you see is a link and the link is broken 2) the pip you are using has the first line which is weird and pointing to an absolute path that does not exist anymore (for example, because you moved the virtual env) 3) something else

Answer (score 3):

you should probably make sure that you the pip from you virtual environment, so sth. like

```
./env/bin/pip install -U --no-deps django-social-auth
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when I had mistakingly set `PYTHONPATH` incorrectly in `~/.bashrc`. If `echo $PYTHONPATH` returns anything outside your expected environment, delete it with `export PYTHONPATH=''` and check your `~/.bashrc` for `PYTHONPATH`.