# Why does pip show packages which were not installed to the site-packages of the current conda environment?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I have anaconda (conda 4.5.11 with the Python 2 version) and I always used pip to install packages inside my environments (I didn't know this was sub-optimal earlier). Some of the packages however, e.g. mock, are unexpectedly in:
Location: $HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
(based on pip show mock)

while other packages, e.g. tensorflow, are in:
Location: $HOME/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages
as expected for the environment.

I have a few other environments and mock seems to be in:
Location: $HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
for them as well.

Why might this have happened?

This was the closest question I found:
[Why does pip installs a package outside my virtual environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448901/why-does-pip-installs-a-package-outside-my-virtual-environment)
But it doesn't solve my problem. (The shebang in the pip script does point to my virtual environment's python executable.)

Comment: Is that other Python on `PATH`?  Conda seems to have issues when other Python's of the same version are also available accessible through environment variables.

Comment: You probably ran `pip` from outside the virtual environment from time to time, and the package are installed in your local Python. Also, your anaconda does not use Python 2 if packages are in `anaconda2/envs/py36`.

Comment: @merv there _are_ other Pythons on the path but their priority is lower than the environment anaconda. When all environments are deactivated, the path is: `$HOME/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`  

When any environment is activated it's `bin` is prefixed to the path and so it has higher precedence.

Comment: @gaFF could you please explain what you meant by 'Also, your anaconda does not use Python 2 if packages are in anaconda2/envs/py36'? Did you mean that it uses Python 3 when I call `python` within the environment? I know that but I mentioned that I used the Python 2 version of Anaconda to make clear which version I use.

Comment: The directory `anaconda2/envs/py36` is named after Python3.6, and so are all your package repositories. So it seems you use only Python 3.6. Try `python --version` in your virtual environment to check.

Comment: You can test if those other Python installations are on your import path by activating a Conda env and checking `import sys; print(sys.path)`. Also, things in`env | grep "PYTHON"` can also take precedent regardless of `PATH` order

Comment: @merv I tried those 2 commands:
`env | grep "PYTHON"` gave
`35:CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/rajanr/anaconda2/bin/python`;

`import sys; print(sys.path)` gives lots of extra egg directories of packages I installed form setup.py I think.
Do you know how, when pip tries to install a package, it comes to know that a package is already installed? Does it read it in a metadata file? If so what file is this?
I managed to go through various pip code files and I think pkg_resources from pip._vendor seems the final low level reading but it's getting to be too much code to dig through for me.

Comment: @gaFF, I'm sorry I didn't phrase my comment clearly. I know it uses Python 3.6 within the environment. What I meant by Python 2 version of Anaconda is the version I downloaded from the Anaconda. I'm not sure if that is relevant for the question. But yes, within the environment, it is Python 3.6 always.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, @merv and @gaFF!
I think it'd probably be more time efficient to just reinstall everything from scratch. So I have decided to stop investigating further.